# VBA generates Error on Mac but not Windows

Tags: excel, vba, macos

This VBA code tracks the activity of PowerPoint slides and store the record in an Excel worksheet, saved on my local drive (same folder as the slides):

```
Dim slideShowRunning As Boolean
Dim counter As Integer
Dim st As Dat
Dim i As Integer
Dim sttime As Date
Dim oxlapp As Object
Dim oxlwb As Object
Dim oxlws As Object
Dim edtime As Date

Sub SlideShowBegin(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)
  st = Date
  sttime = Time
  counter = 0
  Debug.Print " works;1 "
  Set oxlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  Debug.Print " works; 2"
  oxlapp.Visible = False
  Debug.Print " works; 3"
  Set oxlwb = oxlapp.Workbooks.Open(ActivePresentation.Path & "\" & "record.xlsx")
  Debug.Print " works; 4"
  Set oxlws = oxlwb.Sheets("TimeRecord")
  Debug.Print " works; 5"
  i = oxlws.Range("A99919").End(-4162).Row
  oxlws.Range("A1").Offset(i, 0).Value = st
  oxlws.Range("A1").Offset(i, 1).Value = sttime
  Debug.Print " works; 6"
End Sub

Public Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)
  If TypeName(slideShowRunning) = "Empty" Or slideShowRunning = False Then
    slideShowRunning = True
    SlideShowBegin Wn
  End If
End Sub

Public Sub OnSlideShowTerminate(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)
  Name = Application.ActivePresentation.Name
  slideShowRunning = False
  edtime = Time
  Debug.Print " works; 7"
  ivalue = DateDiff("s", sttime, edtime)
  Debug.Print ivalue
  oxlws.Range("A1").Offset(i, 2).Value = edtime
  oxlws.Range("A1").Offset(i, 3).Value = ivalue
  oxlws.Range("A1").Offset(i, 4).Value = Name
  Debug.Print " works; 9"
  oxlapp.DisplayAlerts = False
  Debug.Print " works; 10"
  oxlwb.Save
  Debug.Print " works; 11"
  oxlapp.Visible = True
  Debug.Print " works; 12"
  oxlapp.DisplayAlerts = True
  Debug.Print " works; 13"
End Sub
```

Note:

1. The code stores the PowerPoint slide **Name** along with slide opening
   **time** and slide **closing time**.
2. The details are stores in **Excel Sheet**.
3. I have many slides all with same code. The code is working fine in **Windows**.
4. The code won't work when I run it on **MAC**.

I know there are few changes that need to be done to make it work on Mac but can't figure out what. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What kind of an error?  A specific error?  If so, what is the text/number of the message and with what line of code is it associated?  If this is a non-specific error, provide more details.

Comment: Right now the code works for PC's - a user clicks the start button and it records what powerpoint was started, when the powerpoint is started and stopped, and how long it was in slideshow mode for - it is functional on onedrive right now for PCs.

Comment: I know that you can't make this functional while saving to onedrive for Mac, so I'm trying to change it so that it saves to a local folder (like if I used a flashdrive) - so if anyone need to change the code for these poiwerpoints so that they are executed locally and stored on a powerpoint, that is really appreciated

Comment: Please let me know if you understand it as its just not working and doing the task right now..

Comment: I guess my suggestions in my comment were not clear. I suggest you read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then edit your question to provide needed information to help us help you.

Comment: ok! Ill do it Thank you letting me know

Comment: try changing `"\"` to `Application.PathSeparator` so it is `/` on Mac

Comment: @CDP1802 Is that it?

Comment: Set oxlwb = oxlapp.Workbooks.Open(ActivePresentation.Path & "/" & "record.xlsx")

Comment: @alexG Yes, I don't have a mac so can't help much more.

Comment: This might be a long-standing bug in VBA specific to Macs:  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/officeinsider/forum/all/trying-to-open-word-from-excel-vba-results-in-run/856d9a54-cc92-4ad8-9f49-cae38e7335b7 and https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1170558-create-word-object-not-working-in-office-2016-for-mac.html. I'm having a similar problem, with a variety of rather generic error messages.  If someone knows that cross-applications are in fact possible in VBA on a Mac, please reply!

Answer (score 1):

<sup>(Hijacking AlexG's [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70812536/why-does-vba-macro-generates-error-on-mac-and-not-on-pc-windows#comment125187658_70812536))</sup>

From [Wikipedia](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)):

> A **path** is a string of characters used to uniquely identify a location in a directory structure. It is composed by following the directory tree hierarchy in which components, separated by a delimiting character, represent each directory. The delimiting character is most commonly the slash (`/`), the backslash character (`\`), or colon (`:`), though some operating systems may use a different delimiter.

For example,

- Classic Mac OS used `:` as a directory separator (eg., `Macintosh HD:Documents:Letter`)
- Current macOS uses `/` as a directory separator (eg., `/home/user/docs/Letter.txt`)
- Windows can use either `\` or `/` as a directory separator (eg., `C:\user\docs\Letter.txt`)

Rather than trying to remember all the different symbols, there's a VBA property called **[`Application.PathSeparator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.application.pathseparator)**, which returns the path separator for the *current* operating system.

So, try changing your code from:

```
Set oxlwb = oxlapp.Workbooks.Open(ActivePresentation.Path & "\" & "record.xlsx")
```

...to:

```
Set oxlwb = oxlapp.Workbooks.Open(ActivePresentation.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "record.xlsx")
```

...and **maybe** that will solve your problem.

If not, you'll need to provide more specific information about what error you're getting and where.

I can't test it (and you'll find very little support for Excel on Mac) since not very many people use Excel on Mac — especially VBA.  (Personally, the last time I touched a Macintosh was ~1986.)

There are several differences between Excel for Mac and Excel for Windows. You can read more about them [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel%20vba%20mac%20vs%20windows%20site%3Amicrosoft.com), perhaps starting with [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/overview/office-mac) explanation.

Comment: PowerPoint doesn't have an Application.PathSeparator property. Instead you need to write a function that returns the correct path separator, along the lines of 
#If Mac Then
  PathSep = "/"
#Else
  PathSep = "\"
#End If

   A pity that SO doesn't allow for better formatting in comments; this squib isn't worthy of an answer though.

Comment: Actually when I start PowerPoint and Press Start Button to Activate this Macro, Nothing Happens. But in Windows this Macro is working quite well. I have already added the above changes in it. Still not working. Any Luck?

Comment: @ashleedawg These changes didn't work for me actually though thanks for sharing your thoughts. May be there's someone familiar with Writing Macros on MAC.